# Display the Approver name in a Sharepoint Wiki view

Tags: wiki, content-approval

How can I display the Approver name (or "No 'Approved by' column in wiki page content type ?") in a SharePoint Wiki view?

I have a SharePoint Wiki Library with Approval process enabled with Major+Minor versions.
The whole thing works fine and I have a specific group of users with Approve permission granted.

The "Approve/Reject Items" view is fine, but I cannot find an "Approved by" column.

The "Created by" and "Modified by" columns display the editor name who submitted the page for approval, even the submitter and approver comments are available (one in Version history, the other in "Approver comment" column) but I cannot find a way to display the Approver's name.

How can I display this ?

Comment: Dear Robert, did you find an answer to this question ? I have the exact same problem.

Comment: I tried to create a workflow which starts when a page is approved and updates a custom "Approved By" field with the person who actually clicks "Approve", but it won't work :(
This "Approved by" information seems inexistant ...